# Redox reactions: In order to get as much copper as possible from a reaction, one usually adds an excess of zinc. Why?

Tags: redox

In order to get as much copper as possible from a reaction, one usually adds an excess of zinc. Why? We already have a set amount of zinc needed to reduce all the copper(II) ions. Why should we add an excess of zinc? Is it to make sure that there's enough zinc to react with the copper, or will there be a loss of electrons during the reaction?

Comment: If stoichiometric ratios are used, the kinetic rate of reactions rapidly drops toward the end . With excess of some of reactants, the drop is much smaller.

Answer (score 4):

An excess of zinc is often added to a solution of copper ions. This is to make sure that there is enough zinc to react with copper, because, quite often, part of the metallic zinc used is already oxidized into zinc oxide, specially when metallic zinc is used in powder. Zinc oxide is unable to reduce copper ions.